# How to save a MS Access filtered table as a query in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

I need to be able to save the results of a filtered table in Microsoft Access(2010) as a query. Reports in Access are only dynamic if they are based off of a query. If I based the reports off of a the table itself, it wouldn't save any of the search terms/filter results. In the Access macro builder, the DoCmd.save only saves the current table, I need to be able to do a "save as" in VBA so I can save the filtered table as a query.

Thanks

Comment: The statement "Reports in Access are only dynamic if they are based off a query" seems wrong to me. You can run a report with any subset of data by passing a WHERE condition in the DoCmd.OpenReport command. This is one reason to have no criteria in your report's Recordsource, so you can print all the records or any subset as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build the SQL statement based on the Filter and OrderBy settings of the form.

```
Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "Select ... From MyTable"

If Len(Me.Filter) > 0 Then
    sSQL = sSQL & " Where " & Me.Filter
End If

If Len(Me.OrderBy) > 0 Then
    sSQL = sSQL & " Order By " & Me.OrderBy
End If

Call DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).CreateQueryDef("MyQueryName", sSQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've decided that I might be going about the problem the wrong way. I won't be doing any of the filtering, but rather making it easier for the users to build a report off of their filtered data. Right now, without any code to make it easier, the user has to save the filtered table as a query, then open the desired report which is based off the query they just saved(every time they save the filtered table they replace the query that the reports are based off of). How would I write a macro to save the filtered portion of a table as a query?

Comment: @user748872 - AFAIK, there is no direct means to do that. You need to build the SQL and create the query in code. Keep in mind that you can have a subform which displays your data in datasheet view and do something similar to what I've provided.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think in this case that it'll just be one of those things that the user will have to do. It isn't as user friendly as I would have liked, but at least it gets the job done.